# Proof: The identity matrix is invertible and the inverse of the identity is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

How can i show that: $II^{-1} = I = I^{-1}I$ (the identity matrix is invertible) for all cases. And then proof that: $I^{-1} = I$ (The inverse of the identity is the identity). I don't know how start both proof, any suggestion?

Comment: $I*I = I$ (direct computation) so all properties are clear.

Comment: What property of $I$ distinguishes it from other matrices? Also, how can you test if some matrix $A=I^{-1}$? Finally, can a matrix have more than one inverse?

Comment: I do not have a property that distinguishes it from other matrices. If i need test that $ A = I^{-1}$ i show that $AA^{-1} = I = A^{-1}A$, and no, if a matrix is no singular then it has a only inverse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is the inverse of the identity matrix. Then $AI =IA =  I$. But $AI = IA = A$ as well so $A=I$.

Answer (score 7):

$II=I$, so immediately $I=I^{-1}$. This completes both of your proofs.

Answer (score -4):

AS INVESE OF ANY MATRIX IS GIVEN BY A FORMULA; A-1=[1/|A|]X[ADJ OF A]
BUT HERE WE PROOF BY GENERAL METHOD.
                                      LET  K IS INVERSE OF IDENTITY MATRIX I THEN 
                         WE KHOW THAT AS, KI=IK=I
                                     ALSO,KI=IK=K
                                       SO,I=K  OR  [I=I-1]

SO INVERSE OF IDENTITY MATRIX IS IDENTITY MATRIX.

```
                                ** THANKS**
```